# Has Firebase Auth Emulator performance limits?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ts-jest, firebase-tools

We are running **Jest** tests in a parallel environment.

We have designed multiple test suites for our REST API architecture.

Each test suite needs **Firebase auth tokens** for validating our API routes authentication of our users.

So we initialize these tokens in a setup file containing a beforeAll method.

We're dealing with around 250 tests that needs to be run and our API validates the token in Firebase for each test.

Sometimes, The connection of our **Firebase Authentication Emulator** gets lost while running our Jest tests with the result that not all tokens always get initialized before running a test suite. We get this error:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

We suspect it's a performance issue of the Firebase Auth Emulator since this worked when we used a regular Firebase project in the cloud...

Some Code:

<<*setup.ts*>>

```
export let agentToken: string;
... 10 more users 

beforeAll(async () => {
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

  agentToken = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(fireBaseAuth, email, userPassword);
  ...initialize the rest
});
```

<<*auth.middleware.ts*>>

```
const decodedToken = await getAuth(app).verifyIdToken(token);
```

<<*agent.e2e.spec.ts* and 10 other test files>>

```
describe('(GET) /api/agents/', () => {
    test('No auth token provided (401 Missing Auth Token)', async () => {
        const {status} = await request(server).get(`/api/agents/${agentId}`);
        expect(status).toBe(401);
    });

    test('Claiming information you\'re not (403 Forbidden)', async () => {
        const {status} = await request(server).get(`/api/agents/${brokerId2}`).set('Authorization', agentToken);
        expect(status).toBe(403);
    });

    test('successful get (200 OK)', async () => {
        const {status} = await request(server).get(`/api/agents/${agentId}`).set('Authorization', agentToken);
        expect(status).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Does anyone have the same behaviour? Any solutions? Things we do wrong?

The previous solution of using a regular Firebase project, worked. It stopped working when migrating to the Firebase Emulator...